# sqlAlchemy, concrete inheritance, but parent has foreignKey

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i have 3 classes:

- User
- Employee   <-- not required in the DB
- Manager

Manager inherits from Employee.   User table is **not** related to the inheritance.

So far so good:

```python
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255))

class Employee(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    name = Column(String(30))

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dept = Column(String(30))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'manager', 'concrete':True}
```

It creates User and Manager, which is what I want.

But,

The above breaks if we introduce a ForeignKey in the parent class:

```
class Employee(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    name = Column(String(30))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

the error is:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:

```
Columns with foreign keys to other columns must be declared as @declared_attr callables on declarative mixin classes.
```

so far, I didn't understand **[the mixin docs (link)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html)**

What do I need to allow a foreign-key in my base class (Employee, in this case) ?

Answer (score 39):

You can use mixin like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr


Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255))

class Employee(object):
    name = Column(String(30))
    @declared_attr
    def user_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

class Manager(Base, Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dept = Column(String(30))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'manager', 'concrete':True}
```

ref: [Mixing in Columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-columns)

Comment: Why is this not accepted answer? `@declared_attr` is the right way to go.

Comment: How would you set the user_id in this case? `manager = Manager()` then `manager.user_id = 2` won't work.. do you absolutely need to use synonyms and getter/setter?

Answer (score 0):

[Mixin class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html) is where you can put shared features in (such as common columns, common table options ...etc) then let other concrete (sub)classes reuse the code in the mixin by inheriting it. Mixin class itself is NOT ORM-mapped class and will NOT generate  a database table after migration.

In latest version of SQLAlchemy (1.4.26 , as of writing this answer), if your mixin class doesn't include foreign-key constriant, then it does not need `declared_attr` for declaring common field or  inherit `Base` class.

The code would look like :

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255))

class EmployeeMixin: # Mixin class
    name = Column(String(30))

class Manager(Base, EmployeeMixin):
    # will copy `name` column from EmployeeMixin to this class once migrated
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dept = Column(String(30))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'manager', 'concrete':True}
```